# cannot specify link libraries for target

Tags: ros, libraries, cmake, linking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone. I dont normally run to the forums for healp, but I have been dealing with an issue for two days and I am getting really frustrated. I am trying to interface with a LabJack from within a ROS node. The developers have published a .c file full of functions for native TCP operation. I have compiled it into a shared object library but I am unable to link to it (Upon linking, I get undefined reference errors on the lines where I call functions from the library).
I found a post on this site that says after adding the /lib directory (where my shared object library lives) to the link directories in CMakeLists,  given my lib as libfoo, I add to the CMakeLists file
"target_link_libraries(myNode,foo)"

When I do this, I get the following error

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:36 (target_link_libraries):
Cannot specify link libraries for target "myNode" which is not
built by this project.

I am completely stumped. I am pasting my CMakeLists.txt. file just incase it helps. My node is for a diesel generator, called 'dieselGenerator' and my library (for the LabJack) is called libue9.so. It looks like comments get put in bold here, I dont mean to yell.  I really appreciate your help.

Cheers

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.4.6)
include ($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
#  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
#  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
#set (ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

# Initialize the ROS build system.
rosbuild_init ()

# Set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory.
set (EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)


# Set the name to use for the executable.
set (BINNAME dieselGenerator)

# Set the source files to use with the executable.
#set (SRCS ${SRCS} src/ue9.c)
set (SRCS ${SRCS} src/dieselGenerator.cpp)

# Have ROS autogenerate code used in messages.
rosbuild_genmsg ()

# Set the directories where include files can be found.
include_directories (${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
# Make sure the compiler can find the libraries.
link_directories (${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
target_link_libraries (dieselGenerator ue9)

# Build the executable that will be used to run this node.
rosbuild_add_executable (${BINNAME} ${SRCS})

# List the libraries here.
set (LIBS ${LIBS} ue9)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10890/cannot-specify-link-libraries-for-target/) by [Gideon](https://answers.ros.org/users/362/gideon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 239 on 2011-08-12

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In principle your file should work. The only thing is that you need the target (rosbuild_add_executable) before the target_link_libraries.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Change the lines with these, and make sure they are in the same order as shown.

rosbuild_add_executable (${BINNAME} ${SRCS})

target_link_libraries(${BINNAME} /pathto/libue9.so)

replace pathto with the full path to your libue9.so library file

give it a try and let me know if it works for u.

---

Originally posted by [Zack](https://answers.ros.org/users/949/zack/) with karma: 216 on 2011-08-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zack](https://answers.ros.org/users/949/zack/) on 2011-08-15**:
in the target_link_libraries, there should be a space after ${BINNAME} , i've edited the original post to reflect the changes

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-08-15**:
Can you add your changed CMakeLists.txt file to your original post? The error you listed is from cmake, so before its actually doing things like compiling and linking.

**Comment by [Gideon](https://answers.ros.org/users/362/gideon/) on 2011-08-15**:
I tried that and it still gave me the same error. I then tried compiling my library using g++. Since my library was written in C I had to make a few changes to get it to compile, but everything seems to be working now. How do you use a library written in C without converting it to C++?